# Scikit-learnでクラス数を考慮してデータを分割したい

Tags: python, scikit-learn

以下のように、scikit-learnの関数train_test_splitを用いると、

```
dataset_train, dataset_test = train_test_split(dataset, train_size=0.8)
```

データセットを訓練データとテストデータに分割はしてくれるのですが、
クラス数が多い（例えば100クラス）場合だと、
訓練データとテストデータの各々のクラス数が異なる時があります。
例えば訓練データに含まれるクラス数は100である一方、
テストデータのそれは98となってしまうことがあります。

train_test_splitでは、ランダムシャッフルしてsplitしているだけなので、
クラスに含まれるデータ数がアンバランスな場合、このようなことが起きると思われます。

クラス数もちゃんと保つように、データを分割するには、
どのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 存在することがわかっているクラスのデータを最低１個ずつ作り、分割後のtrainとtestにそれぞれ足せば必ず１つは存在することになりますね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。今のところ、そのような形で自分で実装してみます。すでにscikit-learnにそのような関数があっても良さそうですが、私の調べた限りなさそうでした。

Answer (score 1):

クラス比例を保ちながら分割するには`StratifiedShuffleSplit`を[使用して下さい](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit)。

Comment: 編集後の投稿を見ました。これで良いと思います

Comment: 返答が遅くなりました。試してみましたが、これでうまくいくようです。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score -1):

推測ですが，こういう事ですか？

```
dataset_train, dataset_test = train_test_split(dataset, stratify=dataset, train_size=0.8)
```